# Haversine formula on a Firebird database

Tags: mysql, sql, firebird, haversine, great-circle

I used the following sql for mySQL but I now need to use this for a Firebird database. I have searched and read the Firebird documentation but can't seem to locate an alternative. In Firebird 'radians' and 'limit' both are not supported. Has anyone successfully done similar in Firebird?

```
SELECT zip, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(38.6285426) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-86.05296039999999) ) + sin( radians(38.6285426) ) * sin(radians(lat)) ) ) AS distance 
FROM zipcodes 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance 
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having a similar issue, here was my solution for Firebird that returns all zips codes within a certain mile radius of a Lat/long (Great Circle) in one query.

```
select zipcode from(
SELECT zipcode, ( 3959 * acos( cos( 38.6285426/57.2958 ) * cos( lat/57.2958 ) 
* cos( lon/57.2958 - -86.05296039999999/57.2958 ) + sin( 38.6285426/57.2958 ) * sin(lat/57.2958) ) ) AS distance 
FROM zip_codes)
where distance < 20 
ORDER BY distance
```

Answer (score 4):

The `radians` function in mySQL "returns the argument X, converted from degrees to radians". You don't need builtin function to do that, it's rather simple math: `radians = degrees × π / 180º`. You could create an convenience view with calculated columns for deg-to-rad conversion, to make the query easier to read. BTW, Firebird has [builtin function for retrieving π value](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-pi).

Instead of `LIMIT` Firebird [supports `ROWS` syntax](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-select.html#fblangref25-dml-select-rows):

```
SELECT <columns> FROM ...
   [WHERE ...]
   [ORDER BY ...]
   ROWS <m> [TO <n>]
```

Comment: While I completely appreciate your answer, I probably should have detailed my question a little more. Yes I understand the math and yes it's simple math. mySQL returns all my zipcodes within 25 miles with that one simple query. My question I guess should have been doesn't firebird have a similar option without having to do some separate additional functions and calculations and make things more complex than they need to be in order to get the same result.

Comment: IMO creating an view which has `lat` and `lng` as radians is pretty simple and makes the final query nicer too (instead of `radians(nn.mmm)` you have just `lat` or `lng`). But you could also create an UDF for radians function if you prefer that... but you can't use the MySQL query as is in Firebird, no.

Comment: Sidenote: If you use Firebird 3, you can also create a UDF without having to create a native library to provide the function.